# I'm trying to take an input using Scanner(System.in) but it's not letting me. Help!

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.in

So I'm trying to take an input from a user using Scanner(System.in) but when i try to type something into the console it won't let me.

Can anyone help?

```
Function.show();

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

if (input.equals("a"))
{
    Function.outputFile(1, list);
}

input.close();
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it won't let me"? Does it throw an exception? Does it just hang? Does the program complete but not display anything or change the output file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting to call `next` on the Scanner. Your `if` line should be `if (input.next().equals("a"))`, instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using input.next.charAt(0) in a switch...

```
Function.show(); 

Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

switch (input.next().charAt(0)) {
    case 'a': { 
        Function.outputFile(1, list); 
        break;
    }
    case 'b': {
        etc
    }
```

If you separate it, (I.E. char letter) you can use `switch` (`letter.toUpperCase()`) [in theory... I've never tried it] and then you don't have to worry about `case`.